# TextMeshPro Text only renders on some part of the game screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro, unity-components

I am trying to add `TextMeshPro` on a game object(sprite) outside the UI in 2D world. So I created a sprite to act as the background and `parent` game object then I put a `canvas` as the child of the sprite. Finally I put the `TextMeshPro` as the child of the `canvas`. I set the canvas render mode to world space. I am programmatically adding the sprite game object to the scene. The `TextMeshPro` on some portions of the screen does not show its text but when I move it around, the text shows on other portions of the screen.

[image: Node GameObject]

Above is the structure of game object, the node is the sprite.

[image]

This is the result of the TextMeshPro. Node 1,2 and 3 are showing the text but Node 4 and 5 are not. If I move Node 4 and 5 to the area where Node 1,2 and 3 are, it shows its text.

Comment: Does something speak against having one single Canvas and rather make the `Node` and `Image` and spawn them all as child of the single Canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the canvas and the sprite in the same sorting layer and give the canvas a bigger order, this will make the UI elements appear in front of the sprite.

[image: Sorting layer order]

If the canvas and the sprite have the same order, the display order is related to their distance from the camera.

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. I added a new sorting layer, assigned the layer to both the node(sprite) and the canvas. I then increased the order of the node(2) and the canvas(4) ensuring the canvas has a higher order so that it can be drawn above the node. It is a problem of the order layers, simply increasing the order of the two game objects using the default sorting layer works too but it's good practice to group the sorting layers.